Is it possible to obtain a java.awt.Component reference to the main Eclipse IDE window using the Eclipse API
I'm currently developing an Eclipse plugin that involves creating a JFrame. I'd really like to be able to setLocationRelativeTo the main Eclipse IDE window. However, in all my poking around, I can't find a method in the Eclipse PDE that returns a java.awt.Component. I'm hoping someone out here has additional insight.

Eclipse uses SWT not AWT/Swing so no such method exists.

@greg-449 Ah; so I might need to look into rebuilding my JFrame using the JFace API instead... Thanks for that.

It doesn't look like this is possible. However, I may be able to leverage something that I found here...

That should work, but you end up with two GUI systems with two event loops which can cause issues.

@greg-449 I hadn't considered that. I'll bear that in mind if this is indeed the solution I go with.
